# NetBeans Rich Client Platform: How to hide search bar from the options dialog?

Tags: netbeans, rcp, netbeans-platform, branding

How can I hide or remove the search bar from the options dialog? I can hide the tabs such as General, Editor, Java, A, B, C, X, Y, etc. by editing the layer.xml file but I cannot do the same for the search box since there is no key available for it to be hidden from the layer.

[image: search bar to be removed marked in red box]

Comment: The question seems perfectly clear to me. I have exactly the same issue and would be interested by the answer.

Comment: This is a very specific question regarding a very specific problem. I don’t understand why this question is closed given Stackoverflow is exactly for these kind of questions.